# Weird terminal formatting on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, cmd, terminal

when running a container with Docker my terminal screws up.

[image]

This both happens with powershell and cmd. And only when accessing a docker container.

How can I have it normal?

PS: This happens from when I reinstalled Docker

Comment: What version of Docker? `docker version`

Comment: Docker 17.06.0-ce-rc1

Comment: @eryksun Nope, that didn't solved anything :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with the Docker for Windows release candidate. You can follow [this issue (#786)](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/786) to see when it's resolved, or revert back to the stable release for an immediate solution.